# looking for a word that means when somebody is good at one thing you assume that they are good at other things

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that means when somebody is good one thing you assume that he is good and other things.
Example:
Because a person is a good basketball player you assume that they will be a good basketball coach

Comment: I like the proposed *halo effect*.  Also: *They hired the golden boy from Accounting* suggests that the guy from Accounting got chosen because of his positive reputation.

Comment: It is close enough to [Towel Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towel_Day) that I am tempted to suggest that "hoopy" would be a good answer.  But this would not be generally understood unless you are fortunate enough to have froods as an audience.

Comment: [authority bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases) maybe, but your example is not very good.

Answer (score 2):

One term that fits your definition is the **halo effect**. Here is an extract from an article about it in *The Economist*:

> The existence of the so-called halo effect has long been recognised.
>   It is the phenomenon whereby we assume that because people are good at
>   doing A they will be good at doing B, C and D (or the reverse—because
>   they are bad at doing A they will be bad at doing B, C and D). The
>   phrase was first coined by Edward Thorndike, a psychologist who used
>   it in a study published in 1920 to describe the way that commanding
>   officers rated their soldiers. He found that officers usually judged
>   their men as being either good right across the board or bad. There
>   was little mixing of traits; few people were said to be good in one
>   respect but bad in another.
>
> Later work on the halo effect suggested that it was highly influenced
>   by first impressions. If we see a person first in a good light, it is
>   difficult subsequently to darken that light. The old adage that “first
>   impressions count” seems to be true. This is used by advertisers who
>   pay heroic actors and beautiful actresses to promote products about
>   which they have absolutely no expertise. We think positively about the
>   actor because he played a hero, or the actress because she was made up
>   to look incredibly beautiful, and assume that they therefore have deep
>   knowledge about car engines or anti-wrinkle cream.

https://www.economist.com/news/2009/10/14/the-halo-effect